# Back to C Programming - String seems to be mutated after iterating over the char pointer

Tags: c

I have a code in C as below. Seems that as soon as the for loop starts - last character of the string is over-written and no longer exists.

Can someone please explain this. I see the following response when I write my name. Note that instead of scanf - if I use constant string, it doesn't happen. Please see attached screenshot of the output.
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei8ES.png)

```
void update_string_new()
{
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    char nameString[] = ""; 
    scanf("%s", nameString); 

    char *namePointer = nameString;  

    printf("String before iteration - %s\n", nameString); 

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        namePointer++; 
    }
    
    printf("String after iteration - %s\n", nameString); 
}
```

Comment: This is resulting in undefined behaviour as your char array is initialised to 1 byte in length, the null terminator.  The loop is advancing memory 20 bytes (into unallocated space), it’s only a coincidence it’s ‘working’ at all.

Comment: Thanks - so if I initialize the nameString char array as nameString[5] it seem to work.

Comment: Essentially, the size will be length of string, plus one; for the null byte (terminator).

Comment: You should understand that `char nameString[] = ""; ` is equivalent to `char nameString[1] = ""; `, since in the absence of an explicit number of elements, the number is taken from the initializer.  But ask yourself this:  How much space did you *think* it was going to allocate for the array?  Did you expect it to use some arbitrary number like `10`, or `100`, or `1000`?  Can you see the absurdity of that?

Comment: Carrying on from @TomKarzes point above; *this isn’t Python*.  In C, these things aren’t abstracted away - we need to tell the machine *explicitly* what we want it to do.

Comment: @TomKarzes - yeah just going back C after C#  - need to do the things runtime was doing automatically, but that's the whole purpose. Also still cannot fully imagine the reference and value types - in c there's still a difference, but definitely not same as C#.

Comment: @S3DEV - thanks - yeah I see. Need to calibrate my mind to work with C. Will take time :) Just couldn't understand why can't i read scanf to a char pointer - so that you can assign any length - probably due to the fact that we don't leave anything to runtime right?

Comment: Here's an analogy. You have an empty 1 litre cup sitting on a table. This cup is *allocated* to hold only 1 litre of water. (e.g. 1 byte  of memory). You have a container holding 10 litres of water (e.g. a 10 character string, 10 bytes). You pour the 10 litres of water into the 1 litre cup - where does the remaining 9 litres go? All over the table. Likewise - when you 'pour' (`scanf`) 10 characters into a memory space where only 1 byte is allocated for your string, where are the remaining 9 bytes (characters) going to go?

Comment: Yes, into the memory, but in an uncontrolled (unpredictable / *undefined*) manner.  Takeaway: In order to use `scanf` properly, you must first *allocate a sufficient quantity of memory* to hold the characters (e.g. 'water') being read (e.g. 'poured') into the memory (e.g. 'cup'). C is not 'magically' going to allocate the memory for you, because you haven't told it how much memory you need - remember, *this isn't Python*. We must *tell the machine* what we need it to do, and where to store 'stuff'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment by @S3DEV points out, your code has [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), which means pretty much anything can happen.

The undefined behavior is caused by overflowing the buffer in the `scanf` call. `scanf("%s", nameString)` reads characters from the standard input until a white space character is read and append a null terminator in the end.

In the snippet in the question, `nameString` is a character array whose size is determined from the initializer. `char nameString[] = "";` is equivalent to `char nameString[1]={'\0'};` and the size of the array is one. If `scanf` reads any character, it will attempt to access the array out-of-bound when attempting to write either the second character it has read or the null terminator if exactly one character is read from the standard input. In either case, the out-of-bound write access to the array is undefined behavior.

The usual practice is to estimate how many characters is long enough to hold the user input and declare the array accordingly. For example, if you determine that 31 characters is enough for most user input, you can declare the character array as `char nameString[32];`. The initializer is not necessary if you are going to overwrite the buffer right away in the very next line.

In general `scanf("%s", nameString)` is very hard, if not impossible, to use safely because you don't have control over how many characters the user inputs. The correct way is to use a format specifier with a width. For `char nameString[32]`, we should do `scanf("%31s", nameString)` instead. You can then use `strlen` to check whether the user input is truncated and handle the error accordingly.

Alternatively, if you have C11, you can use the `scanf_s` function instead, the basic usage is `scanf_s("%s", nameString, sizeof(nameString))`. The `_s` class of functions will call the corresponding `constraint_handler` if write may overflow the buffer.

For example, the following calls `abort()` if the user input is too long,

```
    char nameString[32];
    set_constraint_handler_s(abort_handler_s);
    if(scanf_s("%s", nameString, sizeof(nameString)) != 1){
        //handle error, maybe return early, necessary because scanf_s() may return EOF      
    }
    //Continue normal processing
```

Although the answers are a bit out-of-date, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c) and its answers discuss alternative ways to use `scanf` without causing a buffer overflow.

Comment: I see - thanks, a lot of good reference staff. Thank you.

Comment: Since C11 and `scanf_s("%s", nameString, 32);`, `32` is not certainly the right type.  Use `scanf_s("%s", nameString, sizeof(nameString));`.

Comment: "The initializer is not necessary if you are going to overwrite the buffer right away in the very next line." --> except it is not known if `scanf_s()` succeeded - possibly nothing was written.  Better code would check the return value of `scanf_s()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Updated. I originally meant for `scanf` and believed that for `scanf("%s",...)` there is no point to check the return value anyway (it is needed for `scanf("%d",...)` for example), but then I forgot to adapt it when I added `scanf_s`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou "Not necessary in this case because abort() would have been called" --> `scanf_s()` can return `EOF` due to no input.  I am confident that is not a runtime constraint.  Checking return value remains a good test.  UV for improvement.